# Sending certificate with custom attachment in moodle

Tags: moodle

In my moodle 2.6 i would like to edit sending certificate action to send certificate with attachments (my attachment would be 2 file from course) It's always different files but in courses have the same name. 
1 is *pdf and second is mp3 file.
I know that i have to get that file to certificate send mail acrion and add it to email , i don't know how to do it and I need a little help. Can sb help me ?

Thanks for answers 
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed there is a function in /mod/certificate/lib.php that emails the certificate to a student:

```
certificate_email_student($course, $certificate, $certrecord, $context);
```

If you make a copy of that function and modify it for your cron - you will need to change $USER to $user - $USER is the current user but you will need to send it to a specified user.

The function also shows how to get a copy of a file using the file storage api

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API